# newImage placement not at top left

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When I only have this in my main.lua file:

```
local myImage = display.newImage( "somefile.png" )
```

Why is it not actually displayed at top left since it's placed at 0, 0? Some parts of the images are not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup the anchor point for the image you are creating.

This should clarify it all:
http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/

If you want the 0,0 coordinates to be the top left position of the image, you need to set:

```
myImage.anchorX = 0
myImage.anchorY = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with build 2000 of Corona SDK all display objects are drawn with their .x and .y representing the center of the object unless you change the object's Anchor Point to not be centered.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please clarify?

Comment: See this tutoral:  http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/11/06/graphics-2-0-tutorial-roundup/